# $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ as manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I am trying to do this has a while, but I cannot use correctly the regular value theorem to do so!

I appreciate any help. The problem is that I cannot choose the function to take $SU_n$ as a regular value...

I was wondering about the domain as $M_n(R)$ and the codomain as $M_n(R)\times \mathbb{R}.$ The function would be something like $f(A) = (AA^*,\det A)$, then $SU_n = \det^{-1}(I,1).$

Comment: What are you choosing for your domain and codomain for your function for which $SU_n$ is supposed to be a level set?

Comment: @Travis, that is the point, I was wondering about the domain as $M_n(R)$ and the codomain as $M_n(R)\times \mathbb{R}.$ The function would be something like $f(A) = (AA^*,\det A)$, then $SU_n = \det^{-1}(I,1).$

Comment: @Travis, you are perfectly correct, I will corrige this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you wanted to prove first that $\operatorname{U}(n)$ was a manifold. One can show something is a manifold by showing it is an embedded  submanifold of a bigger manifold. I claim that $\operatorname{U}(n)$ is an embedded submanifold of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\Bbb C)$. Indeed, there is a map $\Phi: \operatorname{GL}(n,\Bbb C)\longrightarrow \operatorname{GL}(n,\Bbb C)$ that sends $A$ to $AA^\ast$. This map is in fact equivariant with respect to the smooth action $B\cdot A = BAB^\ast$, so it has constant rank $n^2$ by the following:

The image of its differential at the identity is the set of matrices of the form $A+A^*$ which has dimension $n^2$, so $\operatorname U(n)=\Phi^{-1}(\mathrm {id})$ is an embedded submanifold of dimension $2n^2-n^2=n^2$.

To compute $D\Phi(B)$ note that $\Phi(A+h) =AA^\ast+hA^\ast+Ah^\ast+hh^\ast$ and thus $\Phi(A+h)-\Phi(A)-T(A)(h)=hh^\ast$ is of quadratic order where $T(A)(h) = hA^\ast+Ah^\ast$. This is a linear transformation, and by uniqueness of the differential, it must be the case $D\Phi(A)(h) =hA^\ast+Ah^\ast$, in paritcular $D\Phi({\rm id})(h) = h+h^\ast$, as claimed.

Now show that $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ is an embedded submanifold of $\operatorname{U}(n)$.

Comment: how to do this? I am not sure!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Note that any matrix of the form $B = AA^*$ satisfies $B^* = (AA^*)^* = (A^*)^* A^* = AA^* = B$, so the first component of the candidate function, $$f(A) := (AA^*, \det A),$$ for which $SU_n = f^{-1}(I_n, 1)$, actually maps into the proper ($n^2$-dimensional) subspace of Hermitian matrices.

Comment: ok! I realize this, but I still also don't know how to proceed, could you be more explicit?

Comment: Can you show that $(I_n, 1)$ is a regular value of the map $M_n(\Bbb R) \to \{\textrm{$n \times n$ Hermitian matrices}\} \times \Bbb R$?

Comment: yes, I already did this! So, how to conclude?

Comment: the determinant of a matrix in $U(n)$ is not a reala number but a complex number of absolute value 1.

Comment: @Thomas You're right of course. The important thing for our purposes is that the map onto that (1-dim.) component is a submersion.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi Since you know that value is regular, its preimage $SU_n$ is a regular manifold, and we're done.

Comment: @Travis, I am sorry, I am not able to show that $df$ is a submersion... how can I do this?

Comment: See Example 7.27 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*; it solves the analogous problem for the orthogonal group. I think you'll be able to solve it using that example as a model. https://books.google.at/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&lpg=PP1&dq=lee%20introduction%20to%20smooth%20manifolds&pg=PA166#v=onepage&q=orthogonal%20group&f=false